# AC3 Error 1119 - dynamic instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, static, parent-child

I'm not very familiar with scripting in general or in Actionscript 3, but at current I am working on a sort of motion comic project.

At the end of each 'chapter' I want the comic panel to close, a new button to appear and the layer that prevents pressing on stuff in the background to move outside of the screen. This is the code I use.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, endcomic);

function endcomic(event: MouseEvent): void {
    parent.parent.x = -480;
    parent.parent.y = 0;
    parent.parent.gotoAndStop(1);
    parent.parent.parent.comicclose.x = -1920;
    parent.parent.parent.btn02.x = 1476,2;
}
```

But I keep getting the error

> Symbol 'window01', Layer 'Actions', Frame 8, Line 8, Column 23 1119: Access of possibly undefined property btn02 through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

So apparently it has something do to with the loads of instances in instances I have, yet I cannot quite understand where the problem exaclty lies.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I think You can put comicclose and btn02 in same parent, and set btn02's visible property to false at first. Then in your endcomic function, set btn02's visible to true and set its x position.

Comment: Hmm no that's not it either. I'm still getting the error

Comment: Whoops, pressed the return button too fast.
But the error is still saying

>Symbol 'window01', Layer 'Actions', Frame 12, Line 8, Column 23 1119: Access of possibly undefined property btn02 through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.

Comment: The line  parent.parent.parent.comicclose doesn't throw an error, it means comicclosebtn is valid. So just put comicclose and btn02 together.Or you should debug and find out btn02's parent,then try to set it in the code.